# Angular 2/4 communication between two component via a shared service

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build a simple shopping cart application.
I have two components and a cart service like following.

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-cart></app-cart>
```

In cart service has all the functionality for doing adding an item to cart, delete item in the cart, cart quantity etc.

I need to update the cart count in the header component when the user adds a product to the cart.

How to do that with a shared service.

Comment: What is the question - how to create a shared service or how to get from one component to the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, You can use a service with **`subject`**. A service in Angular is a singleton, meaning it is managed as a single instance. So if each of the components access the service, they will access the same shared data.

```
export class cartService{
    private prodCount = 0;
    prodCountCountChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
    UpdateCount(count: number) {
        this.prodCount = count;
        this.prodCountCountChange.next(this.prodCount);
    }
}
```

In your component you can do this,

```
  this._cartService.UpdateCount(this.prod.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header, you must subscribe to some event in the `Shared Service`. The same event will be emitted from your cart component.

Please have a look at this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/LS1uqB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Subject` from `RxJs`. In your cart you will subscribe to some counter in your service so you'll able to update cart information in `app-header`.

Answer (score 0):

In angular the components will share an instance of a service if it is from the same ancestor. For example you have your `app-header` and `app-cart` wich are part of the `AppModule`. So if you add `SharedCartService` to the `providers` array of your module, the two components will get the same instance of that service.

[Dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#singleton-services) and [hierarchical dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Create a service by :-

```
ng g service data
```

Upon running this, your output may look something like

```
installing service
   create src\app\data.service.spec.ts
   create src\app\data.service.ts
   WARNING Service is generated but not provided, it must be provided to be used
```

The warning simply means that we have to add it to the providers property of the NgModule decorator in src/app/app.module.ts, so let's do that:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
   providers: [DataService],
})
```

Now that we have created a service, let's take a look at what the Angular CLI created:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

now create a function that holds your data in **data.service.ts**

```
constructor() { }
 public currentData: any;
 storeData(dataFromComponent){
   this.currentData = dataFromComponent;
 }
 getData(){
   return this.currentData; 
 }
```

now in **app.component**

```
 import { DataService } from './data.service';

 export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {

  }
   anytimeSaveData(){
      // to store data in service call storeData function
     this.dataService.storeData("Hello! I have some data here..");
   }
}
```

to get data in another component just import our service and call **getData** function

```
 export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {

  }
      // to get data from service call getData function
     console.log(this.dataService.getData());
}
```

**Output in console**

Hello! I have some data here..

Happy Coding