# Data passing between components Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I have been learning Angular 4 for a couple of weeks now. I cannot seem to figure out how to pass data from one component to another as my components were simple before. I figured out that the best for me to use is Behaviorsubject, because I have a form component that fills out from a list component when I edit a customer instead of making a new one.

**CustomerList**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cust-list',
  templateUrl: './cust-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cust-list.component.css']
})
export class CustListComponent implements OnInit {

  isEdit:boolean = false;
  subscription:Subscription;

  customers: any[];
  customer = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  }

  constructor(public dataservice:DataService) { 
    console.log('werkz');
  this.dataservice.get().subscribe (customers =>{
    this.customers = customers;
  });  

  if(this.isEdit){
    this.subscription = this.dataservice.setCust.subscribe(customer => 
 this.customer = customer)
    }
  }
```

**CustomerForm**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cust-form',
  templateUrl: './cust-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cust-form.component.css']
})
export class CustFormComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription:Subscription;

 constructor(public dataservice: DataService){
  this.subscription = this.dataservice.getCust(cust);
 }}
```

**Data.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
public custSent = new BehaviorSubject<object>([]);

    set setCust(customer){
        this.custSent.next(customer);
}

get getCust(){
    return this.custSent.getValue();
}
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If so can someone lead me to what is wrong? If it is not I might need a push in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it work? If not, can you give a [mcve] illustrating the specific problem with it?

Comment: this answer i gave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560989/angular-2-4-communication-between-two-component-via-a-shared-service/46561386#46561386  if not tested then dont post your question

Answer (score 0):

Change service function names as follow (remove `get` and `set`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
public custSent = new BehaviorSubject<object>([]);

setCust(customer){
        this.custSent.next(customer);
}

getCust(){
    return this.custSent.getValue();
}
}
```