# Push object into another component array in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
    Like

    // My First Component
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component1',
      templateUrl: './component1.html'
    })
    export class Component1 {
       books: any[] = ['Java'];
    }

    // My Second Component
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component2',
      templateUrl: './component2.html'
    })
    export class Component2 {
     // Now I want to push 'Angular2' in books array from here. So, How can i do this and remember there is no any relationship of parent child component.
    }
```

I want to push object from Component2 to Component1.

I have already try with Observable.

Can you please help me in above scenario?

Comment: use event emitter or shared service

Comment: I would used a shared service / observable in this case.

Comment: But may event emitter using between  parent child component and there is no any relation ship of parent child.

Comment: Sajeetharan : How can we push object into another component array by service ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560989/angular-2-4-communication-between-two-component-via-a-shared-service

Comment: Hi, Sajeetharan above url dosen't help me.

Comment: Did you check how to communicate between components?

Comment: Yes, I have ever seen document related only communication between parent-child relational component. And here not parent child component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared service to manage that, put provider:[myService] in the highest level module which contains these two component, then it become a singleton object.

```
@Injectable()
class myService{
books=[]
} 

// My First Component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.html'
})
export class Component1 {
constructor(private _myService:myService){
   this._myService.boosk.push('Java')
}
}

// My Second Component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.html'
})
export class Component2 {
constructor(private _myService:myService){
}
}
```

Comment: But it's not reflect in Component2.
Whenever I push Book Name from component one it is not reflecting on component2.
So, How to update in Component2 ?

Comment: this.books=this._myService.books in component 2. Have you provide the service in  highest level module ?

Comment: Yes, I have did same thing in component2.
I have added this code in component2 ngOnInit() -> I am Right ?

Comment: create a plunker. Share service suppose to work

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/7OKOcI7RMovV6lccheGy?p=preview

Comment: the plunker you created is not an angular2 template it won't work. use this 
https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue