# how to display data name with its id in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

sample json:

```
{
name:java, //this is from book component
language:english,//this is from book component
author_id:120130930930, //this is from Author component
}
```

book.comp.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of books" class="list-group-item">
<li>{{book.name}}</li> //displaying
<li>{{book.language}}</li>
<li>{{book.authorId}}</li>
<li>{{book.author.name}} -->//here i need to display author name with help of its id in book component but name is present in author component.
```

servicestorage.ts

```
getBooks() {
    return this.http.get('http:myurl:3000/books').map(data => {
      return data;
    });
  }
 getAuthors() {
    return this.http.get('http:myurl:3000/authors').map(data => {
      return data;
    });
  }
```

how to display author name with help of its id in book component but name is present in author component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the same api to get book and author information, you could create a **`BehaviorSubject`** with desired information and use a **`shared service`** to share the data across book and author component.

sample code

```
export class myervice{
    myData: BehaviorSubject<yourClass> = new BehaviorSubject<yourClass>();
    SaveData() {
        this.myData.next(data);    
    }
}
```

now you should be able to access myData across **[`two components.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560989/angular-2-4-communication-between-two-component-via-a-shared-service)**

Comment: pretty sure you mean this.myData.next(data) and you'll also probably want a behavior subject for this.

Comment: sorry forgot the fact that i created subject :P

Comment: thank you. sorry i am new to angular.Is there any working example for this like stackblitz?

Comment: i have added a example from another answer